# Passing shared parameter to blazorcomponents

Tags: c#, parameters, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Blazor server app that has a side navigation component as well as a top navigation component.

I want the side nav's "selected" status to get cleared if the user selects an item from the top nav menu.

In my `MainLayout.blazor.cs` I have a variable called `ResetSelection`:

```
protected bool ResetSelection { get; set; } = false;
```

I'm passing this from the `MainLayout.blazor` file into both top and side nav components:

```
<SideNav AuthUser="@navAuth.User.GetAuthUserModel()" ResetSelection="@ResetSelection" />
<TopNav AuthUser="@Auth.User.GetAuthUserModel()" ResetSelection="@ResetSelection" />
```

In `TopNav.razor.cs` I check if a nav item has been selected, and if it has, I set the variable to `true`:

```
private void itemSelected(MenuEventArgs<CategoryModel> args)
{
    // if item selected set the main nav selected item to null
    // breakpoint gets hit-- this method gets fired as expected
    ResetSelection = true;
}
```

In the `SideNav.razor.cs` component I use an `OnParameterSet` to check if the param is `true`, and if so I clear the current selected nav item and reset the variable to false:

```
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    base.OnParametersSet();
    
    if (ResetSelection == true)
    {
        // we never get here!
        NavMenu.UnselectAll();
        ResetSelection = false;
    }
}
```

I don't ever get the `OnParametersSet` triggered with a `ResetSelection == true` condition-- and I don't understand why. I can't seem to make this interaction work between two child components.

Is the parameter passed in being scoped to the local component when it has its value changed in `TopNav.razor.cs`?

Comment: You need to trigger an event on change. The Side nav needs to listen for this event and call StateHasChanged

Comment: I have used [EventCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#eventcallback) for stuff like this several times. Works like a charm and is relatively straight forward.

Comment: You can use the observer pattern. https://remibou.github.io/Implementing-observer-pattern-in-Blazor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Blazor Notification Pattern to your problem.

This approach gets away from the fragile spaghetti plumbing inevitable when you try and create more than simple Parameter/Callback relationships between parent/child components.

Create a simple State object and then cascade it.  `readonly` and `IsFixed` prevents RenderTree cascades: renders are driven by events.

State Object:

```cs
public class MenuState
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? StateChanged;

    public void NotifyStateCahnged(object? sender)
        => this.StateChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Your layout.

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="_state" IsFixed>
    //... layout markup
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private readonly MenuState _state = new();
}
```

Then wherever you use it:

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<h3>TopMenu</h3>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private MenuState State { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.State.StateChanged += this.OnStateChanged;

    protected async Task MenuClicked()
    {
        // do whatever maybe async
        // emulate an async action
        await Task.Delay(10);
        this.State.NotifyStateCahnged(this);
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // only need to render if it wasn't me who triggered the event
        if (sender != this)
        {
            // Do whatever
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => this.State.StateChanged -= this.OnStateChanged;
}
```

An alternative to the cascade is to register `MenuState` as a Scoped Service and then inject it where you need it.