Blazor Force all child components refresh
How to force all childs refresh even if no child parameters are changed by parent?
Actually is there any way to call StateHasChanged() on parent and all childs refresh?

Why if there are no changes?  If you have changes to say a service or a cascaded object that impact a component down the render tree, use the notification pattern.

See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256650/i-need-to-update-state-of-blazor-component-when-other-component-changed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447173/can-a-blazor-element-access-data-in-a-peer-element and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216339/passing-shared-parameter-to-blazorcomponents/75219347#75219347

I need TimeStampViewer, but The problem is, for a color to change in every component, There will be a lot of redundant codes  this.myProvider.TimeStampChanged += this.OnChanged;, ... and all the components should have this. I want this for dark mode.

There are several ways to do this.  This is probably the simplest.  It uses a Guid cascading value.  When you set a new Guid to the cascade, all components capturing the cascade will render.
First a base component.  All components that need to update inherit from it.
public class StampComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter(Name ="Stamp")] private Guid Stamp { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
}

A demo component that must update.  Note it inherits from StampComponentBase rather than directly from ComponentBase.
@inherits StampComponentBase

<div class="alert alert-primary m-2">@(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())</div>

And a demo page:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Update">Render Components</button>

<CascadingValue Name="Stamp" Value="_stamp">
    @* These all update *@
    <TestComponent />
    <TestComponent />
    <TestComponent />
    <TestComponent />
    <TestComponent />
    <TestComponent />
</CascadingValue>

@* These dont *@
<TestComponent />
<TestComponent />

@code {
    private Guid _stamp = Guid.NewGuid();

    private void Update()
    {
        _stamp = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    }
}

Note that any direct child components that implement a ChildContent parameter will always render.
